# Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that 'ApplicationData' conform to 'ObservableObject'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm reading a book called SwiftUI for Masterminds 4th Edition. I've pasted one of the examples it gives below. But it causes an error:
`Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that 'ApplicationData' conform to 'ObservableObject'`

I noticed if I change the class declaration to this the error goes away:

`@Observable class ApplicationData: ObservableObject {`

But why does that fix the error? Doesn't the class already conform to ObservableObject? It seems like Swift doesn't know it conforms unless I state it explicitly via the type? I'm confused why the book gave the example without "ObservableObject". Is that a good way to do this, with both the @Observable macro and the ObservableObject type?

```
import SwiftUI
import Observation

@Observable class ApplicationData {
    var title: String = "Default Title"
}

// Listing 6-52: Assigning the observable object to the view's environment
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State private var appData = ApplicationData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appData) // error: Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that 'ApplicationData' conform to 'ObservableObject'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Observable` is a completely different system from `ObservableObject`. If you want to use `@Observable`, use `.environment(...)` and `@Environment(ApplicationData.self)`. Otherwise conform to `ObservableObject` and add `@Published` properties, and remove `@Observable`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app environmentObject is a typo you need environment

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject notice that in this link Apple explicitly discourages mixing Observable and ObservableObject

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answers @lorem ipsum and @Sweeper. Now I understand I was mixing two different approaches. So I think either one of these is acceptable:

1. Conform to ObservableObject and inject via environmentObject

```
class ApplicationData: ObservableObject {
    var title: String = "Default Title"
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State private var appData = ApplicationData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appData)
        }
    }
}
```

or

2. Wrap with the @Observable macro and inject via environment

```
@Observable class ApplicationData {
    var title: String = "Default Title"
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State private var appData = ApplicationData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(appData)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro